# how can i check if an item is in local storage using indexes(special case)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I'm trying to figure out, how I can fix this problem, I'm trying to store some html code to an array of html string code, if both ids matches, but it turns out after debugging, I've been getting something completely different than what I thought I would be getting, here's what i mean.

**PROBLEM:**

After debugging for a little bit now, I'm not sure that when you get a key in the local storage API that it gets the actual key versus where it returns the index of that key, Or I don't really know how the local storage API works properly. If what I said doesn't make sense, please look at the outputs(expected vs actual).

**Note**: the way I'm also storing the keys into the local storage, is by giving each item in a list an ID, starting from "0" and incrementing by 1 all the way till end of the Data received from an API. For example if I get 9 items, all those items should have ids starting from 0 all the way till the 9th item.

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
let not_favored = [...document.querySelectorAll(".not-favored")];

for(let index =0; index<not_favored.length;index++ ){


   // Allow type cast instead of doing it manually, recall '==' allows type casting while '===' doesn't
   console.log("the index of the children is " + not_favored[index].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].id + " and the index of the local_storage is " + localStorage.key(index+"") )
   if(not_favored[index].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].id == localStorage.key(index +"") && localStorage.key(index+"") !== null){
       console.log("how many times this occurs? Does it even work or compare key, which is the ID with the right index of that ID?")
       not_favored[index] = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(index.toString()))

    }
    else{
       not_favored[index] = not_favored[index].outerHTML;
     }
```

**OUTPUT(INCORREECT)**

```
the index of the children is 0 and the index of the local_storage is 2
the index of the children is 1 and the index of the local_storage is 3
the index of the children is 2 and the index of the local_storage is null
the index of the children is 3 and the index of the local_storage is null
the index of the children is 4 and the index of the local_storage is null
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
the index of the children is 0 and the index of the local_storage is null
the index of the children is 1 and the index of the local_storage is null
the index of the children is 2 and the index of the local_storage is 2
the index of the children is 3 and the index of the local_storage is 3
the index of the children is 4 and the index of the local_storage is null
```

Comment: Why the `index+""` in `localStorage.key(index+"")`? Why not just do `index.toString()`?

Comment: @GaborSzekely I've tried that, and had no impact at all.